# Why <div class="clear"></div> instead of <div class="clear"/>?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I just realized that:

```
<div class="clear"/>
```

after a series of floating divs causes layout havoc, while

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

works fine.

**Can anyone explain this?**

This is the CSS:

```
div.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<div class="clear"/>
```

If you are serving an XHTML page as `text/html`, browsers aren't reading it using a real XML parser. They're using a plain old HTML parser which doesn't know about self-closing tags. To an HTML4 parser, that's just an open tag with some weird punctuation in it. (If browser parsers really used the rules of SGML, it would be some other undesirable thing completely, but they don't.)

Until IE9 becomes widespread, we won't be able to serve general-purpose web pages as `application/xhtml+xml`, which is what's required to make the browser use real XML parsing rules. Until that time, if you write XHTML documents you will need to make your documents also backwards-compatible with plain HTML, which means *always* and *only* using self-closing syntax on elements that are declared to have an `EMPTY` content model. (`img`, `br`, etc.)

There are more rules about what you have to do to write HTML-compatible XHTML, but that's the most important one. [Appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) of the XHTML 1.0 standard is a list of the differences; it looks a bit complicated, but many of the points address features you don't want to be using anyway, and some are now irrelevant as they're talking about being ancient browsers like Netscape 4. The practice of putting a space before `/>` is no longer required by anything in common use, for example.

Comment: "Until IE ${whatever} I'll be 100 years old"

Comment: The behavior will probably also change if you put a DOCTYPE at the head of your page.

Comment: DOCTYPE doesn't affect the parser mode; even with a propert XHTML doctype, the browser will still use the traditional HTML parser if the document is served as `text/html`. Of course not having a doctype and thereby being in Quirks Mode can indeed mess up a number of *other* behaviours to do with CSS floats thanks to its emulation of IE5-era bugs...

Answer (score 12):

According to the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/), [Section 7.5.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4), the `<div>` tag requires a closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="clear"/>
```

This syntax isn't valid HTML/XHTML. Any tag which ***can*** contain content ***cannot*** be self closing (even if no content is required in the tag. Therefore content containing tags like div, span, p etc, can never be self closing tags. Conversely, tags which cannot contain content like `<br />` should always be self closing.